# how do I use angular cli on a Windows Server in a Jenkins build batch command

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, path, angular-cli

before installing Jenkins I ran this:
**npm install -g @angular/cli**

but I also have this in devDependencies in the package.json for the project:

**"@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.32.3"**,

---

when running a Jenkins build, I get this message in the log:

*'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

=======================================

Here is the Windows batch command in Jenkins:

**cmd /c call npm install**

**set Path=%WORKSPACE%\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin;%PATH%**

**echo %PATH%**

**ng build -prod**

========================================

here is a little more log output from Jenkins:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\UiUnitTests>**ng build -prod**

*'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.*

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\UiUnitTests>exit 9009 
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

---

but when I run this just from the command line (not in a Jenkins job), this works fine:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\UiUnitTests>**ng build -prod**

#### Your global Angular CLI version (1.0.0-rc.1) is greater than your local

#### version (1.0.0-beta.32.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global warnings.versionMismatch=false".
Hash: 7853ecb5a81a25eadbeb
Time: 61317ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.7aaf5284cd5921eea40b.bundle.js (polyfills) 278 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.3380f71d3e71966aea27.bundle.js (main) 371 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.9db1bafdfc989b37db97.bundle.css (styles) 69 bytes {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.24574fc8320129058fac.bundle.js (vendor) 2.18 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.d1f5b52100bed2568d44.bundle.js (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\UiUnitTests>

================================================

last but not least, here is the Jenkins log output from  **echo %PATH%**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\UiUnitTests>echo C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\UiUnitTests\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\UiUnitTests\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\cfn-bootstrap\;C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Comment: Not going to put this as an answer, but for me, putting 'call ng build --prod' stopped it quitting the script after running the ng build.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Do not install the CLI globally.

Run the `npm install` for the repo and any time you need to run an `ng` command use this:

```
node_modules/.bin/ng [command goes here]
```

This will save on install time and ensure there are no differences between your local and global versions.

*Additional commentary: Update your app to the latest version of the CLI*

Comment: You don't need to run ng directly. If you use the npm scripts the correct ng commands will be executed for you. For instance, you can run "npm run build -- --prod" to create the dist folder for prod.

Comment: works great, thank you! Having the CLI installed globally won't hurt but it is not the solution.

Comment: @SebastianBallarati Jenkins do not allow to install Angular CLI globally

Comment: closely related but slightly off topic - some users may find this helpful ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68244224/ng-add-angular-fire-error-cannot-run-login-in-non-interactive-mode/68244350#68244350

Answer (score 4):

Try `npm run ng build`. The only issue with this is it omits any other parameter like `--prod` or `--test` after build.

Following are the commands what i am using to run my angular build successfully from Jenkins.The last command is executed the dirty way by setting up the path variables. Don't know if there is a cleaner way to do this. This does execute the commands properly without omitting anything.

```
@echo on
cmd /c npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

echo yarn Install
cmd /c yarn

echo Build
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin;
ng build --prod --aot=true
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, fails with `ERROR: Task not found: "npm"`. Previously it was something like `ERROR: Task not found: "ng"`. Executing `npm install -g @angular/cli` additionally to `npm install` also didn't help.